# Can that function parameter really be pointer-to-const?

Tags: c, pointers, clang-tidy

In the following C program, functions `f`, `g`, and `h` are essentially identical, however clang-tidy says that parameter `p` can be pointer-to-const in `g` and `h` (but not in `f`). My understanding is that `p` can't be pointer-to-const in any of them. Is that a false positive?

```c
struct S { int *p; };

extern void x(struct S *s);

void f(int *p)
{
    struct S s;
    s.p = p;
    x(&s);
}

void g(int *p)
{
    struct S s = { .p = p };
    x(&s);
}

void h(int *p)
{
    struct S s = { p };
    x(&s);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    f(&a);
    g(&a);
    h(&a);
}
```

Output from clang-tidy:

```
$ clang-tidy --checks=* a.c
Error while trying to load a compilation database:
Could not auto-detect compilation database for file "a.c"
No compilation database found in /home/wolfram or any parent directory
fixed-compilation-database: Error while opening fixed database: No such file or directory
json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: No such file or directory
Running without flags.
2 warnings generated.
/home/wolfram/a.c:14:13: warning: pointer parameter 'p' can be pointer to const [readability-non-const-parameter]
void g(int *p)
            ^
       const 
/home/wolfram/a.c:20:13: warning: pointer parameter 'p' can be pointer to const [readability-non-const-parameter]
void h(int *p)
            ^
       const
```

Tried with clang-tidy versions 10 and 11.

The following may be related: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41393

Comment: What happens if you change the order of the calls to `f`, `g` and `h`? Or give different arguments (i.e. addresses of different integers) to each call?

Comment: @AdrianMole that changes nothing. I can even remove the main function altogether, the result is the same.

Comment: Definitely looks like clang-tidy bug. This parameter cannot be a pointer to const, in neither of the functions. Try it, change it to pointer to const - you will probably get another warning, on assignment discarding const qualifier.

Comment: The bug you referenced looks like exactly that issue - it probably has some trouble parsing struct initializes. Seems you answered your own question.

Comment: Reported as a clang-tidy bug to the LLVM Bugzilla: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool is bugged. The intention of this warning is to likely to enforce "const-correctness", something that only matters when the pointer is actually de-referenced inside the function. You don't de-reference the pointers.

But more importantly, the C language requires this for simple assignment of pointers (6.5.1.6.1), emphasis mine:

> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
>   the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
>   pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed
>   to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

Making the pointer parameter `const` would turn `s.p = p;` and similar into constraint violations - invalid C. The rules of initialization follow the rules of simple assignment too, so the various functions behave identically.